# determine language (mode) by filepath in ace

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using the Ace-Editor to modify several different files. In order to determine the correct mode, I wrote a simple switch, which looks like this:

```
function getMode(path){
    switch( getFileExtension(path) ){
        case "html": return "html";
        case "htm":  return "html";
        case "css":  return "css";
        case "bat":  return "batchfile";
        ...
        default: return "text";
    }
}
```

However, to cover all supported languages in ace, I would have to frequently update this list.

It would be nice, if Ace could tell me which mode is the right one, and so I found `function getModeForPath(path)` in ace: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ext/modelist.js#L11

How can I call and use this function in my own code? Or how is this function supposed to be used?

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do is, to make a small dropdown-box where the user can select the language. And the default-language is determined by the filepath. (Similar to sublime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using prebuilt version from ace-builds repository, include `src/ext-modelist.js` file with ace, then do

```
var modelist = require("ace/ext/modelist")
modelist.getModeForPath(path)
```

see also https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.5/demo/kitchen-sink/demo.js#L306-L311

Comment: The require-function returns `undefined`. It doesn't seem that it even starts an ajax-request. I used the `src` prebuild version I downloaded it yesterday

Comment: Yes, it doesn't start a request, it only gives already loaded modules. You need to include ext-modelist.js file first.

Comment: I thought that "require" would automatically load the file, if it hasn't been loaded already. Thanks, now it's working

Comment: What is the path @auser, how ace can detect mode by editor content??

Comment: @RahmanUsta detecting mode by editor content is whole another story, it's quite error prone, and Ace doesn't provide built in method for that.